# Why is $c((n+1)H_n^\ast) = c(H_n^\ast)^{n+1}$ for the total Chern class c.

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space, characteristic-classes

I'm currently studying with the Book "From Calculus to Cohomology" by Madsen & Tornehave(free PDF [here](https://archive.org/details/MadsenI.H.TornehaveJ.FromCalculusToCohomologyDeRhamCohomologyAndCharacteristicClasses1996/page/n193)). 
In the Example 18.13 there is a claim(within a calculation), that 
 $$c((n+1)H_n^\ast) = c(H_n^\ast)^{n+1},$$ where $c$ denotes the total Chern class, $H_n$ denotes the canonical line Bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I have already understood the rest of the calculations, but somehow, I can't feel sure about this one.. maybe I just need sleep, but I need to know for certain why this is, before tomorrow morning.

My guess was, that it has something to do with the fact, that we have(18.9(ii) in the book)
$$ f^\ast c_k(\xi) = c_k(f^\ast(\xi)) $$
for a complex vector bundle $\xi$.

Please punch me if I am totally wrong.. 
What calculation rule is causing the property above?...

I know it might be totally trivial, but please don't hesitate to state the fact, even if it's trivial af..

Comment: $(n+1)H_n^*$ is their notation for $(H_n^*)^{\oplus(n+1)}$.  Now remember the total chern class maps direct sum of bundles to the product of total chern classes: $c(E\oplus F)=c(E)\cdot c(F)$